# How to mock hierarchy getters using when...then

Tags: junit, mockito

I want to mock a line of code which is

```
List<Status> Status = xyz.stream().filter(Predicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I tried using mocks

but its throwing null pointer in Mockito. How can I mock this line so that my list is not empty and returns what I pass through thenReturn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mock each part in the chain.

```java
Ung mockedUng = Mockito.mock(Ung.class);
when(mockedUng.getFguBeskaeftigelseStatus()).thenReturn(fGUBeskaeftigelsesStatusList);
when(mockforloeb.getUng()).thenReturn(mockedUng);
```

Comment: I have tried this but stil fGUBeskaeftigelsesStatusList values r not getting set to the main method list.

Comment: Are you sure that your re passing the mockforloeb to the tested class?

Comment: I did not get you... When I am creating the values and adding them to the list in test class, I should do mockedUng.set(fGUBeskaeftigelsesStatusList) or ung.set?

Comment: I added my test class could u point where am i going wrong

Comment: When you have a mocked class do not call setters on it.You need to do ```when(mockung.getId()).thenReturn(1L);``` instead of ```mockung.setId((long)1);``` etc.

Comment: ok...so when i mock and set values....this line is throwing null  List<FGUBeskaeftigelsesStatus> beskaeftigelseStatus = forloeb.getUng().getFguBeskaeftigelseStatus().stream().filter(fguBeskaeftigelsePredicate).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: without mocks it worked for me, I set values with the class objects in test and sent it to the tested method....after the if blocks satisfied, the list is no more empty...its taking values. Thanks.